# C言語のコンパイラをいれたい

Tags: c

【ググってコンパイルを何かのマネージャーから入れて環境変数設定して実行までできました。ありがとうございました。】
今回c言語をノートパソコンで動かしながら確認したいと思い、コンパイラを入れようとしていますが、なぜかインストールでエラーになります。

みなさんどうやってコンパイル入れたのか教えていただけると・・・

Comment: 他の人が助言・回答(しやすく)するための(PCのハード/ソフトの種類/容量や版数とかC言語コンパイラや開発環境の種類や版数、そして行った作業と通知されたエラーメッセージの)具体的な情報が書かれていません。こちらのヘルプ記事を参考に内容を追記してみてください。[良い質問をするには？](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: プラットフォームも, コンパイルの目的もはっきりしないのでよく分からないけれど, trial and error で何か処理行う(行っていく)(とする)なら [tinycc](http://download.savannah.gnu.org/releases/tinycc/) 使います、

Answer (score 1):

> みなさんどうやってコンパイル入れたのか教えていただけると・・・

自分は Microsoft Visual Studio Community 2022 です。

Visual Studio Community
https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/ja/vs/community/

Comment: それはコンパイラや開発環境も含めたすべてのやつなんですかね？

Comment: コンパイラだけ入れたいと思いましたがエラーばかりなので、vs community2022いれてみます、ありがとうございます。